# Why the output of Theano shared variable is an array?

Tags: python, theano

I am using my own dataset to train a SdA using Theano with this code:

```
train_set_x = theano.shared(np.asarray(x, type=theano.config.floatX))
train_set_y = T.cast(theano.shared(np.asarray(y,dtype=theano.config.floatX)), 'int32')
```

Then I am printing train_set_x and train_set_y with this code:

```
for x,y in zip(train_set_x.get_value(), train_set_y.eval()):
    print ("x=", x)
    print ("y=", y)
```

And these are my result:

```
('x=', array([ 1., 0.36037669, 0., 0.06552909, 0.46260971,0.45968048,.27107092,  0.16942367,  0.09178392,  0.35540537, 0.38170689,  0.1973381 ,  0.22643969]))
('y=', 0)
```

As you can see the output is a numpy array. However when I am printing the  MNIST dataset in SdK.py provided by theano tutorial, by these codes:

```
datasets = load_data(dataset)

train_set_x, train_set_y = datasets[0]
valid_set_x, valid_set_y = datasets[1]
test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]

for x,y in zip(train_set_x.get_value(), train_set_y.eval()):              
    print ("x=", x)                                                       
    print ("y=", y)
```

I see these results:

```
x= [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          
  0.0703125   0.0703125   0.0703125   0.4921875   0.53125     0.68359375
  0.1015625   0.6484375   0.99609375  0.96484375  0.49609375  0.          ...
```

As you can see this is not a numpy array. Do you have any idea how can I fix my codes and dataset in a way that my ouyput looks like the Theano tutorial output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Theano tutorial is written in Python3 and you're using Python 2.x.

To get the same output format for Python 2,x, you can just remove the parenthesis after `print`.

```
a = numpy.asarray([1,2,3])
print ("x=", a)  # this will output ('x=', array([1, 2, 3]))
print "x=", a  # this will output x= [1 2 3]
```